# VBA quotation marks in excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do the multiplication as below, but keep getting an error. I know it's because the quotation marks are missing - probably at the end, but I don't know where to add it

```
Dim val1 As Double
Dim val2 As Double

' here will be IF Then 

val1 = Range("G" & i).Value
val2 = Range("H" & i).Value

'or
val1 = 2.1
val2 = Range("A150").value

'or
val1 = sheet("Anotherworksheet").Range("F" & lastRow).value
val2 = findValue() 'function return value

'it is not important where and what data I get


Range("D4").Formula = "=" & val1 & "*" & val2 
'formula is important because I need to know what values I get
```

*question updated

Comment: Why not just use `Range("D4").Formula = "=G5*G6"` ? There are no quotation marks needed in a formula that has no string values.

Comment: because ultimately cells will be variable (based on for i = 1 to lastRow)

Comment: Then you may want to update your question that demonstrates this. It seems you may have oversimplified things.

Comment: Note that `Range("D4:D100").Formula = "=G5*G6"` will write `=G5*G6, =G6*G7, =G7*G8...` in cells `D4, D5, D6`... respectively. It would be best you post the complete code with explanations what you are trying to achieve. An image or two (before, after) may also be helpful.

Comment: question updated, but I don't think it matters. Basically, I want to be able to multiply variable values ​​(val1, val2) and add them to the cell through a formula.

Comment: If you can't show the complete code, could you explain what is wrong with your code? If the values are `3` and `4` then the formula in cell `D4` will be `=3*4` but the cell will display `12`. If the values are "Yes" and "No" the formula in cell `D4` will be `=Yes*No` but the cell will display `#Name?`. But it's not going to happen if you're trying to do this in a `UDF` (user-defined function).

Comment: `val1, val2` aren't variables containing cell addresses, so trying to put them in a spreadsheet formula rather than simply computing the product in code is unmotivated at best. They won't update automatically. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Also -- the code that you posted throws no error (beyond the `Sheet` for `Sheets` typo). Please provide a [mcve]. As it is, you haven't given anyone enough information to replicate the problem.

Comment: You write "formula is important because I need to know what values I get". That makes some sense, and what you have posted should actually work. But, if the intention is for a user to be able to know where a certain number comes from, perhaps you can add that as a comment (easy enough to do from VBA) rather than using a formula with constant terms as a de facto comment.

Comment: everything I wrote is correct. if I want to multiply something times 2.1 the value (val) has to be a string. Then it works. If a value is taken from a formula or function, you can pass it through a function like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905412/vba-double-as-string-with-comma-and-not-point